# Meaning of 'each of which is contained in a single $A_{\alpha}$,' in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Lemma 1.15. of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology says: if a space $X$ is the union of a collection of path-connected open sets $A_{\alpha}$ each containing the base point $x_0\in X$ and if each intersection $A_{\alpha}\cap A_{\beta}$ is path-connected, then every loop in $X$ at $x_0$ is homotopic to a product of loops each of which is contained in a single $A_{\alpha}$.

I am wondering what exactly is the meaning of 'each of which is contained in a single $A_{\alpha}$.' Does it mean that for each loop in the product, there exists a $A_{\alpha}$ that fully contains it? Or does it mean that for each loop in the product, there is a unique $A_{\alpha}$ that fully contains it? The distinction being that in the first case, a loop in the product might be a subset of $A_{\alpha}\cap A_{\beta}$ whereas this is excluded in the second case.

I am struggling to follow the associated proof and I think that clearing up what we are trying to show would help me out. Furthermore, I have been told that it is important to understand this Lemma because it leads to van Kampen's Theorem. Thanks!

Comment: I reckon it's "there exists an $A_\alpha$" not "there is a unique $A_\alpha".

Comment: I've thought about it and I think I agree. I think the proof makes sense if that's what we're trying to show. But I'm not super confident so if someone would care to confirm with some certainty, that'd be great.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered for awhile, but I though I'd throw my two cents in:

Suppose that $f:I\rightarrow X$ is the loop in question. For each $A_\alpha$, we get an open set $f^{-1}(A_\alpha)$ and these sets cover all of $I$. By Lebesgue's Number Lemma, there exists some $\delta>0$ so that if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $[x,y]\subseteq f^{-1}(A_{\alpha})$. You essentially choose your partition based on this. I was taught this explanation in my topology course, and it made a lot more sense to me than what I saw in Hatcher, so I figured I would include it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a doubt in understanding the proof of the above-mentioned lemma, which was also due to the term, "single $A_{\alpha}$", being used. In particular, the part where Hatcher mentions that $V_s$ can be taken to be an interval whose closure is mapped to a single $A_{\alpha}$.

My attempt to solve it is as follows:
Let $s \in I$ such that $f(s) \in A_\alpha \cap A_\beta$ for some $\alpha, \beta$. Now, consider some open neighbourhood $V_s$ in $I$ which is mapped to some $A_\alpha$. For the sake of simplicity, let $V_s=(s_i,s_{i+1})$. Now, consider $(s_i,s)$ where $f(s) \in V_\alpha \cap V_\beta$. As the closure of ${(s_i,s)}$ is $[s_i,s]$, it is mapped to a single $A_{\alpha}$. Note $f([s_i,s]) \subset A_\alpha \cap A_\beta$ but $f([s_i,s]) \cap A^c_\alpha = \phi$.

Hence $V_s$ can be taken to be an interval whose closure is mapped to a single $A_{\alpha}$. I hope it clears your doubt.